# how to get stocktwit message volume chart data for an ticker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stocktwits

I want to display [stocktwit] message volume chart for an ticker same as is displayed on StockTwit page in my MVC4 project. I looked for the api's but couldnt find it.

how can i get this data using stocktwit api?

Please help.

Thanks,
Vikas Nale

Answer (score 0):

Hi Vikas at this time that data is not available in the API. 
It is an interesting request, and something we will consider and put on our roadmap. Most companies looking to do that will license our data to do just that and then add it to their trading algorithms.

Comment: Hi Chris, Has this feature been added? It does not look like it has. Otherwise is there a process to follow to license this data for an individual?